# How to set a website redirection basing on server time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create a website redirection at a specific time based on server time, hence having no time delays between users with some time difference. I need a redirection at precise time.
I have used this code, but people had different time on their devices, hence nothing worked out. Even a difference in 2 seconds is a lot for my case.
code:

var intervalId = window.setInterval(checkTime, 500);

function checkTime() {

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var s = d.getSeconds();

if(h == 13 && m == 10 && s == 0) return window.location='landingpage.html';
```

}

Please help

Comment: In order to redirect based on server time, you're going to need to get the time from the server, and store that as a JavaScript variable. `new Date()` in front-end javascript will return the client's time, not the server time. What kind of backend are you using?

Comment: Also, I just want to mention that client-side redirection is ok, but keep in mind that users can turn off Javascript or stop the redirection if they want to, so depending on your use case, you may need server-side redirection as well.

Comment: @BenNyberg, thank you so much for replying. I am not sure how to do that at all, since I'm a bit of a beginner. Regarding the back-end code, if I understood you correctly, I am using HTML, JS and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from limitation on Client-Side redirection, as Ben mentioned, to really make it global you should use UTC time.

```
var h = d.getUTCHours();
var m = d.getUTCMinutes();
var s = d.getUTCSeconds();

if(h == 13 && m == 10 && s == 0) return window.location='landingpage.html';
```

but remember, a user can change the time in their computer, or fake a wrong timezone and trigger your redirect earlier than anticipated.

Alternately if you use server-side script to set the date it will be same for every browser. Here is an example in php:

```
var d = new Date("<?= date('D M d Y H:i:s O') ?>");
```

Comment: thank you for your response @NawedKhan. In my case all the computers are located in one room, and have approximately the same time with difference of 2-3 seconds. Maybe there is a way of creating a server time, on which I will base the redirection time? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, just like Ben suggested in his comments. You would use server side (php, asp, jsp etc.) to define the value for d. in this case all computers accessing the page will have exactly the same date.

Comment: And how exactly would you do that @Nawed Khan? Could you please help me out? I have tried implementing PHP, but it did not work at all. Most likely I have done something completely wrong.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include server-side code. So instead of reading browser date with new Date(); we set new Date(datestring) where datestring is printed by php.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have used the code, but unfortunately it doesn't redirect to the page.

Comment: when you look at the source of the page you should see the date in Date("...date..here..."); you can do alert(d) to see what date, if any, are you getting

Comment: I am sorry for being so annoying, but I truly don't know where to find the date in the source of my code. I have open the source code via firefox and a window popped out with my code, but nothing else...

Comment: you should search for "var d = new Date(" and you will see that Date("") is either empty, have a date string or the date('D M d Y H:i:s O') thing.

Comment: I have the "date('D M d Y H:i:s O') thing". Do I have to put the time in it? For example the current time?

Comment: this means it is not processing php. A server side script is processed by server and your file extension should be filename.php. Look into how to create server-side php script. It requires web server that can process php.